# Are there means (formal rules or conventions) of use-mention distinction in Japanese writing?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

With English, when writing and looking to mention a word (as a word vs wanting to use the word as its semantic referent), writers have at their disposal quotation marks (punctuational) and italicized font (typographical) with which to make clear their intention.

As examples:

> *The* is the definite article of the English language.

and

> 'The' is the definite article of the English language.

both make clear, via typographic and punctuational devices respectively, that the first *the* they contain is being used differently and means something different than the two other instances of *the* that follow.

Is there anything (typographical or punctuational —as with English— or otherwise —I know Japanese often employs [平仮名]{ひらがな} marker words to indicate things that English would via typographical effects or punctuation) afforded to writers writing in Japanese which can be leveraged to similar effect?

I ask 'cause, as someone learning Japanese, much of what I write in Japanese is meta; I'm usually asking about Japanese itself —about vocab, aspects of grammar like particles, *et cetera*. As such, in terms of mention vs use, many parts of my writing are mention and I worry that, without some sort of annotation, the distinction may be less than clear.

Here's the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) on use-mention distinction in English writing for reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「鉤【かぎ】括弧【かっこ】」 is probably what you're looking for.  Example:

> 「は」は係助詞です。

These are used like quotes in English.

There's also a doubled-up form that can be used if the text is already quoted.

> 教師は微妙な表情をして、「『は』は係助詞です。」と言いました。

Comment: Good answer, but it would be even better if you also mentioned katakana, which is also frequently used, similar to italics in English.  You can find examples by searching Google Scholar for any common grammatical form in katakana.